# What happened to codesaga tfs/svn history viewer?

Tags: svn, tfs, history, viewer

What happened with this fine tfs/svn history viewer? The codesaga.com domain seems to be governed by some other entity. It seems that project is not maintained anymore?

Answer (score 0):

The code is uploaded to [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/codesaga/).
But the log shows no activity since Dec 19, 2008

Answer (score 0):

yep, CodeSaga project had been stopped